# does files on ntfs have uid and gid?

Tags: ntfs, file-permissions, ntfs-3g

I see that NTFS files have SID.But I'm using ntfs-3g user mapping, I'm able to map UID to SID of NTFS file but unable to find windows GID of the NTFS file. Does windows NTFS files have a GID?

In Linux is there a way to find Windows UID and GID of files on NTFS? ntfs-3g user-mapping gives SID of few files but I cant find it for the file I want.

Comment: What is a GID?
I don't like the extensive use of abbreviations that I consider less common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr: No.

NTFS file system entries have an *owner*, which is basically the same as the user ID you’d have on Linux.

The group ID is part of the octal permission system on Linux. Windows does not have that, instead it relies purely on Access Control Lists (ACLs). ACLs can contain entries for any principal type (user, group, whatever).

It doesn’t look like there’s any facility in NTFS-3G or the native NTFS module that allows reading SIDs (owner or ACL entries) on Linux.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the default in `ntfs-3g.usermap` is to map the Windows "Users" group (RID 513) – which, conveniently, most Windows files have in their ACL – to the Linux "users" GID and show it as the owner-group of files.